# Datetime strptime(): Unconverted data remains: 0

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, valueerror, strptime

I am using pandas, and I'm trying to convert the following string column "df['Date/Time']" to the datetime format %H:%M.

```
0    0630  --> should be 06:30 etc.
1    1300
2    2400
3    0800
4    1030
5    1300
6    0001
7    0900
8    0900
9    0800
Name: Date/Time, dtype: object
```

I also removed any whitespace using:

```
df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```

However, when I try to convert the string cells to the desired format, I get the error that not all data could be converted.

```
df['Time_reformatted'] = df['Date/Time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%H%M').strftime('%H:%M'))

--> ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0
```

I don't really understand where the 0 could be that causes the trouble. It is the strptime argument that raises the error...any ideas?

Also, is there a more elegant way for using that many lambdas? ;)

Comment: Seems like you have a rogue 0 value somewhere in your data. As for the `strip` method you can simply call `df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'].str.strip()` without having to use a lambda explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are getting is because of the invalid value `2400`, the hour value can not be `24` the maximum it can be is `23`, look at the [Python datetime format docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for more info . And since, the datetime format specifier doesn't understand it, you'll have to implement your own logic for conversion:

```py
import datetime
def parse_times(val):
    val = val.strip()
    h, m = int(val[:2]), int(val[2:])
    if hrs:= m // 60>0:
        h += hrs
        m = m - hrs*60
    h = h%24
    return datetime.time(hour=h, minute=m).strftime('%H:%M')

df['Date/Time'].apply(parse_times)

#output
0    06:30
1    13:00
2    00:00
3    08:00
4    10:30
5    13:00
6    00:01
7    09:00
8    09:00
9    08:00
Name: Date/Time, dtype: object
```

Or, slightly different logic with minute calculation then converting to proper hour and minutes:

```py
import datetime
def parse_times_ii(val):
    val = val.strip()
    h, m = int(val[:2]), int(val[2:])
    minutes = h*60 + m
    hr = minutes//60
    minutes = minutes - hr*60
    hr = hr%24
    return datetime.time(hour=hr, minute=minutes).strftime('%H:%M')

df['Date/Time'].apply(parse_times_ii)

#output
0    06:30
1    13:00
2    00:00
3    08:00
4    10:30
5    13:00
6    00:01
7    09:00
8    09:00
9    08:00
Name: Date/Time, dtype: object
```

Comment: @FObersteiner That will work specifically for 2400 value, the proposed solution will work if OP has many different such out of range values

Comment: Didn't mean to criticize your answer, sorry. Just want to mention an efficient alternative *for certain situations*.

Comment: Of course! That makes perfect sense, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

simple string operation does the trick **if you just need to clean "2400" values**. EX:

```py
import pandas as pd

# clean 2400, make sure no single "0" values remain
df["Date/Time"] = df["Date/Time"].str.replace("2400", "0000", regex=False).str.zfill(4)

# insert colon
df["Date/Time"] = df["Date/Time"].str[:2] + ":" + df["Date/Time"].str[2:]

df["Date/Time"]
0    06:30
1    13:00
2    00:00
3    08:00
4    10:30
5    13:00
6    00:01
7    09:00
8    09:00
9    08:00
Name: Date/Time, dtype: object
```